# bash: moving files to original directory based on filename?

Tags: bash, subdirectory

I've got a bunch of subdirectories with a couple thousand PNG files that will be sent through Photoshop, creating PSD files. Photoshop can only output those to a single folder, and I want to move each one back to their original directory - so the new file foo_bar_0005.psd should go to where foo_bar_0005.png already is. Every filename only exists once.

Can somebody help me with this? I'm on OSX.

Comment: You should add more detail about what you've tried and any code you've made.  SO isn't a code writing service but we're happy to help.  In the meantime, you'll likely want to look into `find` and `mv` as stringing them together here in a script could get you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might start from this minimal script:

```
#!/bin/bash

search_dir="search/png/from/this/directory/"
psd_dir="path/to/psd/directory/"

for psd_file in "$psd_dir"*.psd; do
    file_name="$(echo $psd_file | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\).psd$/\1/g')"
    png_dir="$(find $search_dir -name $file_name.png | grep -e '.*/' -o)"
    mv $psd_file $png_dir
done
```

But note that this script doesn't include any error handlers e.g. file collision issue, file not found issue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Each file found with this `find` is piped to a Bash command that successively make the psd conversion and move the .psd to the .png original directory.

```
psd_dir=/psd_dir/
export psd_dir

find . -type f -name '*.png' | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'n=${1##*/}; echo photoshop "$1" && echo mv ${psd_dir}${n%.png}.psd ${1%/*}/; echo' \;
```

The echo are here to give you an overview of the result.

You should remove them to launch the real photoshop command.